C# .NET ApiController NoContent 204 response cannot map to ProblemDetails response body
I want to render a ProblemDetails (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc) response body from a NoContent() response.
{
    "type": "string",
    "title": "string",
    "status": 0,
    "detail": "string",
    "instance": "string"
}

According to docs, ProblemDetails, ProblemDetails will not automatically render from any status code less than 400.
I have played around with modifying Program.cs with
builder.services.AddProblemDetails
ProblemDetailsFactory, etc. 

(see documentation link above).
No matter what I do, I've not had luck with 204.
Has anyone done this successfully, can it be done? Any pointers in the right direction?
namespace Company.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class ImportantController : BaseController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [ValidateModelState]
        [Route("/api/important")]
        [Produces("application/json")]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<ImportantDataResponse>), 200)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetImportantData([FromQuery][Required] string dashboardId)
        {
            // ...
            try
            {
                IEnumerable<ImportantDataModel> objResult = await _circuitBreakerPolicy.ExecuteAsync(() => _service.GetImportantData(dashboardId));

                if (objResult.Count() > 0)
                {
                    return Ok(objResult);
                } 
                else 
                {
                    return NoContent();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                throw;
            }

            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}


I tried using middleware to intercept method, and customize the response, but I got a result: 'Writing to the response body is invalid for responses with status code 204.' of Exception,

According to the definition of HTTP status codes, 204 status code means "No Content", which means the response is successful but no content is returned to the client. Therefore, when you set the response status code to 204, any content set in the response body will not be sent.
If you want to indicate that the resource is not found or does not exist, you can use return NotFound(); 404 status code to indicate it. The following is an example that you can use as a reference:
[HttpGet]
[Route("/api/important")]
[Produces("application/json")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<ImportantDataResponse>), 200)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(ProblemDetails), StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
      
 public async Task<IActionResult> GetImportantData([FromQuery][Required] string dashboardId)
{

     try
     {
         var objResult = new List<ImportantDataModel>
     {
          
     };

         if (objResult.Count() > 0)
         {
             return Ok(objResult);
         }
         else
         {
             return NotFound();
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw;
     }
     return BadRequest();
}


Update
In the action method add the if condition about the no content, like this:
if (objResult.Count() > 0)
                {
                    return Ok(objResult);
                }   
               else 
                {
                         var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
     {
         Type = "No Content",
         Title = "No Data Found",
         Status = 204,
         Detail = "No important data found",
         Instance = HttpContext.Request.Path
     };
     return new JsonResult(problemDetails);

                }


Yes, I got the same issue when trying to use the middleware approach.  I, however, want to return a "content" body with Title and Description in response as a ProblemDetails when a genuine "NoContent" is encountered.  I'm hoping someone has done this.

I updated the code.

Our team decided to swap to a 200 response with a wrapper summarizing the data, so a no response would have a summary: {  count: 0, message: "parameter yields no data" }
